# C# - Stack Push operation does not work even after Correct Generic constraint

Tags: c#, generics, stack, generic-constraints

```
namespace ConsoleApp3
{
    class Program
    {
        // Main method - entry point of program
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var animals = new Stack<Animal>();
            ZooCleaner.Wash(animals);
        }
    }

    //Simple classes declared and inherited.
    public class Animal { }
    public class Bear : Animal{ }
    public class Camel : Animal { }

    public class Stack<T> //Basic stack implementation
    {
        int position;
        T[] data = new T[100];
        public void Push(T obj) => data[position++] = obj;
        public T Pop() => data[--position];
    }

    public class ZooCleaner
    {
        public static void Wash<T>(Stack<T> animals) where T:Animal
        {
            //Why I cannot do this? I have correctly stated that 'T' can 
            //be of type Animal or can derive Animal but this
            //still causes compilation error!

            animals.Push(new Animal()); //Error: Cannot convert from 'Animal' To Type T!!
            animals.Push(new Bear()); //Error: Cannot convert from 'Bear' To Type T!!
        }
    }
}
```

**Question:**

In Wash() method I have correctly made Generic Parameter 'T' that it would be of Type 'Animal' or can derive from 'Animal'. So why can't I do push operations to insert objects of Animal or Bear ?

Why does `animals.Push(new Animal()); animals.Push(new Bear());` causes compilation error ?

Answer (score 2):

This is normal and expected. If you have a `Stack<T> where T : Animal`, then you must imagine that `T` could be something like `Giraffe`. The only thing you are allowed to push on a `Stack<Giraffe>` is a `Giraffe` or something that *is* a `Giraffe` (a `MasaiGiraffe`, a `NubianGiraffe`, etc). You can't push a `Bear` or an `Animal`: it **must be a `Giraffe`** (or better).

In the case of `T`, that means you can push a `T` - perhaps a `new T()` (via the `T : new()` constraint).

If you want to be able to push any `Animal`: don't use `Stack<T> where T : Animal` - use `Stack<Animal>`.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to C#. This is a very very annoying restriction of C# compiler. You would expect this to work in any other language as it makes sense in OOP paradigm.

OP I hope you're aware that there is a implementation of stack in C# already. If it has the same issue with not accepting inherited types then you can use a wrapper that contains this generic item. It's a pain but you chose CS.

So you'll have to do a work around. It won't be a fun workaround either. Here it is:

```cs
> public class Stack<T>
  {
    public int position => data.Count - 1;
    IList<T> data = new List<T>();
    public void Push(T obj) => data.Add(obj);

    public T Pop()
    {
        var ret = data[position];
        data.RemoveAt(position);
        return ret;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"Num of elements: {data.Count}. {data}";
    }
  }

> public class Animal { }
  public class Bear : Animal{ }
  public class Camel : Animal { }

> var sta = new Stack<Animal>();
  sta.Push(new Animal());
  sta.Push(new Bear());
  sta.Push(new Camel());

> sta
[Num of elements: 3. System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Submission#1+Animal]]

> while (sta.position >=0)
{
    var x = sta.Pop();
    Console.WriteLine($"Popped element type: {x.GetType()}");
}
Popped element type: Submission#3+Camel
Popped element type: Submission#2+Bear
Popped element type: Submission#1+Animal
```

If any C# genius has a better way around this please let me know, as this is a very annoying restrictions with generics. Generics should allow inherited classes like other languages.

Comment: No, you wouldn't expect it to work. The OP's method takes a `Stack<T>` where `T` is an `Animal`. So it could be called with `Wash(new Stack<Camel>);` In that case, trying to push a `Bear` or `Animal` would be an error. Because neither `Bear` nor `Animal` is a `Camel`.